# Android - Read out XML Data

Tags: java, android, xml

I read out XML files fairly often, but now I have a problem. The most XML-Files I worked with had this kind of scheme

```
<datas>
<data>
<movietitle>Harry Potter</movietitle>
<movielength>120</movielength>
<movietitle>Harry Potter 2</movietitle>
<movielength>120</movielength>
</data>
</datas>
```

But this time, the XML file has the following format which confuses me because I don't know how to get the information out

It's kinda like this

```
<dict>
<key>Movietitle</key>
<string>Harry Potter</key>
<key>Movie length</key>
<string>120</key>
</dict>

<dict>
<key>Movietitle</key>
<string>Harry Potter 2</key>
<key>Movie length</key>
<string>120</key>
</dict>
```

So how do I get the information out with this kind of XML file and with Android/Java?

Comment: Quite impossible, really... To the question: what is it you find challenging, exactly? The way i see it: you iterate through the dict nodes and then you use switches to sequentially gather the values in pairs...

Comment: Hi, this is the xml-file: http://www.10000flies.de/?format=plist&complete_list=1

Comment: As i already stated, i do not believe this is a duplicate (even though the title suggests it). The question regards unusually formatted xml and the **specifics** of reading documents formatted in this way, which could in fact differ quite a bit from reading xml files formatted otherwise... If the op still requires assistance, they can contact me and i'd be glad to take this to chat...

Answer (score -1):

in XML file, there should be only one root note. By following this rule, you can easily parse the XML file. I believe that that xml you are reading is not generated by you. if it is on your hand, than kindly make one root node in that xml file and then parse it. :)

let me know if still need any help in this. :)

Comment: check this out :  http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t143337-multiple-root-nodes.html   this post is also saying the same thing.

Comment: i really doubt the xml in the OP's examples represents full xml files (for one a declaration is missing, also the OP clearly states that they have prior experience in reading xml files which would suggest knowledge of formatting)... And this hardly answers the question which as i understand it concerns the unusual format of the data.

Comment: hmmm... my answer was for clearing the thing of xml rules, so it can help. Not for down rate. nwys thanks for that.

Comment: I believe such information would be better suited for a comment...

Comment: @RipalTamboli where is there more than one root element. `<datas>` is the root element. and there can be more than one `<data>` element ie more movies. i think the problem is `<string>Harry Potter 2</key>` the start and end tag are not the same

Comment: @Raghunandan There are two root elements in the second example. Haha, nice catch ^_^, though i believe that's a typo... Hope the OP clarifies soon.

Comment: @StefanDenchev i think op has pasted it twice coz the contents are the same. any way that is not an issue here

Comment: @Raghunandan: i believe you haven't seen the second XML code posted by Stefan. look at that xml file. in that file more than one root element named "dict". better to read entire post and then comment.

Comment: I haven't posted anything... @RipalTamboli Nah, it's doubled in the first example as well, though you're right, it probably isn't relevant...

Comment: sorry its loomie. haha... ;)